# Angular routing not working in Samsung Tizen default browser

Tags: angularjs, routes, samsung-mobile, tizen

I'm facing an strange issue in Samsung Tizen phones. I'm using

```
$location.path('/someurl')
```

In my Angular mobile web app, URL has been updated, but the corresponding view is not coming up, i.e. the previous view has not been replaced by the new one. All my code works fine in desktop and other mobile phones.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have already used `$timeout` but no success. Any suggestion?

Comment: you should probably show the code to make the issue reproducible

Comment: On click  of a button i am simply using $location.path('/xyz')  return ;nothing else .

Answer (score 0):

Use    **$apply()** like this.

```
app.run(function ($location, $window, $rootScope) {
      $window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
          $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            $location.path("/abc");
            console.log($location.path());
          });
      });
    });
```

Comment: I didn't get it  can u explain it ?